# I always get a problem if the image is already created

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sharp

This project changes the image sizes this project is using a library called sharp, but at first, if the image is created for the first time, it does not cause problems, but it always shows me that problem if it was already created.
In `imageProcessing.ts` File

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import fs, { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs';
import resizingTheImage from "./resizingTheImage";

const imageProcessing = async(req: Request, res: Response, next: Function): Promise<void | string> => {
    const widthValue = <string>req.query.width;
    const heightValue = <string>req.query.height;
    const nameFileValue = <string>req.query.namefile;

    const outputDir = `../../images/imageOutput/${nameFileValue}${widthValue}_${heightValue}.jpg`;

    const makeDir = async (): Promise<void> => {
        await fsPromises.mkdir('./images/imageOutput');
    };

    const imageProcessing = async (): Promise<void> => {
        try {
            await resizingTheImage(widthValue, heightValue, nameFileValue);
        } catch {
            res.send('There is a problem with the image processing');
        }
    };

    if (fs.existsSync(outputDir)) {
        return outputDir;
    } else {
        makeDir();
        await imageProcessing();
    }

    next();
}

export default imageProcessing;
```

In `resizingTheImage.ts` File

```
import sharp from "sharp";

const resizingTheImage = async (imageWidth: string, imageHeight: string, fileName: string): Promise<void> => {
    const imageDir: string = `./images/${fileName}.jpg`;
    const outputDir: string = `./images/imageOutput/${fileName}${imageWidth}_${imageHeight}.jpg`;

    if (isNaN(parseInt(imageWidth) && parseInt(imageHeight)) && fileName) {
        console.log("the inputs is Invalid")
    } else {
        await sharp(imageDir)
            .resize(parseInt(imageWidth), parseInt(imageHeight))
            .toFile(outputDir);
    }
}

export default resizingTheImage;
```

In `error`

```
[Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'E:\Image Processing API\images\imageOutput'] {
  errno: -4075,
  code: 'EEXIST',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: 'E:\\Image Processing API\\images\\imageOutput'
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new folder every time. with `await fsPromises.mkdir('./images/imageOutput')`  You can remove it and try.

Comment: @ŞahinErsever I know so I wrote this code
```
    if (fs.existsSync(outputDir)) { return outputDir; } else { makeDir(); await imageProcessing(); }
```